# better regular expression for splitting sentences in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, pattern-matching

I am working on something that counts how frequently a word appears in a bunch of text, tells in which sentence(s) it appears, and sorts the result by the frequency of each word. For example:
[image: sample input and out put]

and this is what I have so far:

```
File.open('sample_text.txt', 'r') do |f| # open a file named "sample_text.txt"

content = f.read # turn the content into a long string

# split the string by sentences
sentences = content.split(/\.|\?|\!/).each do |es|

  es.split(/\W|\s/).each do |w| 
     #split into individual words 
     #and for each word, find matched words in the content

  end

end
end
```

**Questions:**

**1.**
Is there a better regex for splitting the sentences? Now, `split(/\.|\?|\!/)` will take `web 2.0` as two sentences `web 2` and `0`.

**2.**
Can anyone give me some hint on how to do the part that returns an array of sentences that a word is in?

Comment: If proper formatting were used, you should check for punctuation followed by two spaces.  This is one reason why double spaces should be used after punctuation delimiting sentences, other than for aesthetics and just being a decent human being in general.  Live on, double spaces.  Live on.

Answer (score 1):

1. How about requiring a space after the period (or punctuation like `?` or `!`) and then optionally preventing it from being preceded by certain well-known abbreviations (e.g. `vs.` or `Mr.` or `Mrs.` or `i.e.` or `e.g.`), and perhaps requiring there to be a capital letter afterwards?
2. Given an array of sentence strings and a method that splits each sentence into an array of words (I'll leave that up to you), you could do this:

   ```
   sentences_for_word = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = [] }
   sentences.each do |sentence|
     words_for_sentence(sentence).each do |word|
       sentences_for_word[word] << sentence
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: 1.but how can u add those exceptional words to the regex?

2.thanks! =)

Comment: Check out [The Stanford Parser][1]. It has a Ruby binding and methods like `getSentencesFromString`.

  [1]: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

Answer (score 1):

here is a full working sample

```
require 'pp'
content = "Meet Mr. Jon. Jon is a computer programmer and lives in Connecticut. Jon is tall. Shouldn't take web 2.0 as two sentences. And this is a new sentence. "
words = {}
content.gsub!(/(Mr)\.|(Mrs)\./,"\\1{dot}").split(/\. |\? |\! /).each_with_index do |sentences, index|
  puts "\n#{index}: #{sentences}"
  sentences.split(/ +/).each do |word|
    word=word.gsub(/{dot}/,"\.").downcase
    puts word
    words[word]=words[word]||[0,[]]
    words[word][0]+=1
    words[word][1]<<index
  end
end
pp words
```

the last pp gives

```
{"meet"=>[1, [0]],
 "mr."=>[1, [0]],
 "jon"=>[3, [0, 1, 2]],
 "is"=>[3, [1, 2, 4]],
 "a"=>[2, [1, 4]],
 "computer"=>[1, [1]],
 "programmer"=>[1, [1]],
 "and"=>[2, [1, 4]],
 "lives"=>[1, [1]],
 "in"=>[1, [1]],
 "connecticut"=>[1, [1]],
 "tall"=>[1, [2]],
 "shouldn't"=>[1, [3]],
 "take"=>[1, [3]],
 "web"=>[1, [3]],
 "2.0"=>[1, [3]],
 "as"=>[1, [3]],
 "two"=>[1, [3]],
 "sentences"=>[1, [3]],
 "this"=>[1, [4]],
 "new"=>[1, [4]],
 "sentence"=>[1, [4]]}
```

You could filter out words like "a" based on a minimum length of put them on a black list.
Curious on what you are working, me i'm building an indexer for a wiki since i can't get Xapian at work on my windows/ruby.
Grtz

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your regex by adding a positive look ahead assertion

```
(?:\.|\?|\!)(?= [^a-z]|$)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vc4o)

`(?= [^a-z]|$)` is a positive loookahead that checks if there is a space followed by a non lowercase letter OR the end of the string ahead. This brings already a good improvement on the matching.

The other suggestion from Phrogz (preventing to match on common appreviations) is not possible within the regex in one step, because Ruby does not support lookbehind assertions.

A possibility requiring more steps to achieve this would be to search in a first step those appreviations and replace them with a placeholder (e.g. Mr. with Mr#DOT#) and after you splitted on the dots replace the place holders again.

**Just for fun, NOT working with Ruby! the look behind version:**

```
(?<!\be\.g|\bi\.e|\bvs|\bMr|\bMrs|\bDr)(?:\.|\?|\!)(?= |$)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vc4u)

Answer (score 0):

Use the word boundary matcher: str.split(/\W+/).  It will work for most texts (although I guess it will split on the ' character).